# Flags for `ios_base` are all static const integral variables. How come one can change them with `ios_base::setf()`?

Tags: c++, constants, iostream

As can be seen in the header file `<xiosbase>`, class `ios_base` is derived from `template <class Dummy> class _Iosb`, where the following `static const variables` are defined:

```
 static const _Fmtflags skipws = (_Fmtflags)_IOSskipws;
 static const _Fmtflags unitbuf = (_Fmtflags)_IOSunitbuf;
 static const _Fmtflags uppercase = (_Fmtflags)_IOSuppercase;
 static const _Fmtflags showbase = (_Fmtflags)_IOSshowbase;
 static const _Fmtflags showpoint = (_Fmtflags)_IOSshowpoint;
 static const _Fmtflags showpos = (_Fmtflags)_IOSshowpos;
 static const _Fmtflags left = (_Fmtflags)_IOSleft;
 static const _Fmtflags right = (_Fmtflags)_IOSright;
 static const _Fmtflags internal = (_Fmtflags)_IOSinternal;
 static const _Fmtflags dec = (_Fmtflags)_IOSdec;
 static const _Fmtflags oct = (_Fmtflags)_IOSoct;
 static const _Fmtflags hex = (_Fmtflags)_IOShex;
 static const _Fmtflags scientific = (_Fmtflags)_IOSscientific;
 static const _Fmtflags fixed = (_Fmtflags)_IOSfixed;
```

How come these flags can be changed with the member function ios_base::setf() ? Aren't they constant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into GCC's implementation, `ios_base:setf` looks like this

Add only version

```
   inline fmtflags              
    setf(fmtflags __fmtfl)       
    {                            
      fmtflags __old = _M_flags; 
      _M_flags |= __fmtfl;       
      return __old;              
    }
```

Add/remove version

```
inline fmtflags                           
setf(fmtflags __fmtfl, fmtflags __mask)   
{                                         
  fmtflags __old = _M_flags;              
  _M_flags &= ~__mask;                    
  _M_flags |= (__fmtfl & __mask);         
  return __old;                           
}
```

i.e. it changes member variable `_M_flags`

static const variables you are looking at are just convinience predefined values for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that these members **aren't** changed; `setf` sets some non-const member (probably private/protected).  You can probably examine the relevant header to find out exactly what your implementation does.

Comment: What is changed then when you call for example cout.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield) ?

Comment: @user1577873: It's implementation-specific.  Like I said, take a look at the relevant header file if you want to know exactly what your implementation is doing.

Comment: Given the example cout.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield) and clicking with mouse right button over hex, in Visual Studio 2010, and selecting "Go to Definition", that's where the compiler takes me, i.e., to the class _Iosb mentioned before.

Comment: @user1577873, you should click on `setf` instead

Comment: @user1577873: Right, and in there you will see the definition of `setf`.